# Visual Studio 2012 and Itanium target

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, itanium

I can't find clear indication regarding Itanium support in Visual Studio 2012. The IDE (VS 2012 Premium Release as included in MSDN subscription) lets you set corresponding target for C++ or C++/CLR project, but complains about missing toolset when you try to compile the Itanium target. I did find older articles saying that Itanium support would be dropped in VS 2012 altogether, but the target can be created, so I am confused. Any ideas?

Comment: I repro with Ultimate.  It isn't available in the packages on the DVD either, looks like it is gone but not purged yet.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for checking, at least I know that we should not search for or purchase Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to set Platform Toolset option to v100 for Itanium target, then the target can be built (I have VS 2010 installed, so I assume that toolset v100 comes with VS 2010 and may not be available on a clear machine with only VS 2012 installed).